# How to prevent submitting an empty perforce changelist?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, perforce, windows-scripting

This is my batch script and My plan was to tweak my script not to submit empty changelist everytime ,When there is a empty changelist my Jenkins job fails but I don't want the job to fail rather it can succeed..

```
%p4% -p %p4port_store% -u %p4.user% -c %p4.client% reconcile -ade %WORKSPACE%\... %p4% -p %p4port_store% -u %p4.user% -c %p4.client% submit -d "Latest  xml files"> file1.txt
@echo off 
( for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('find "//" ^< "C:\Enlistments\perforceoutput.log"') do (
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%c in ("%%b") do (
echo(File: %%~nxc
echo(
echo(Action: %%a
echo(
echo(File Version: %%d
echo(
echo(Path: %%~pb
echo(
)
)
)>"%Email_body%"
```

Pls advice how to fix this situation..

Comment: I tried to edit the question and format your code but there are strange things like `%` not attached to `%file1` as it should and the first `do` not on the same line with `for` as it should be. Please edit the question and carefully recheck the code, then format it by selecting and pressing Ctrl-K.

Comment: Can you check the results of `p4 opened -c default` before trying to create and submit a changeset?

Comment: You might get more help if the script was readable.

Comment: I tried that getting "File(s) not opened on this client". Still getting No files to submit from the default change list.

Comment: @Senthil Was that a reply to me?  You could use `p4 -z tag opened -c CLN` to avoid the "File(s) not opened on this client" message if there are no opened files.  If the files are in a numbered changeset instead of in the default one, specify the number instead of `default`.

Answer (score 0):

The [p4 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin) allows you to use a 'Post Build Action' to 'Publish' changes to Perforce.  You can shelve or submit the change, please refer to the [docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin#publishing-build-assets) for details.